# Jquery mobile changePage after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile, sap

I have a probleme with ah changePage.
I want to switch the Page after an Ajax call.

If the form get submit, this function will be executed, but after the ajax call the page does not switch.

If I wanna set a Breakpoint on this call, it do not stop.

What can I do, that I can switch the page after the ajax call.

```
$("#serialNumber").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mobilemain.do",
            data: "serialNumberInput=" + $("#serialNumberInput").val(),
            success: function(msg)
            {
              $.mobile.changePage("#machine_manuals", "slide");
            }
        });
    });
```

---

Edit:

Ok!
I found some hint to my Problem.

The SAP-Server call is from the form-submit and not from my ajax-call.
He never goes in the method above.

On my Server, I made that:

```
l_view = create_view( view_name = 'main.htm').
call_view( l_view ).
```

But I does not wanna call the main.htm . 
I wanna call the second page in the jquery mobile project. (main.htm#machine_manuals)

How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Other than the page you are changing to, all options for $.mobile.changePage are passed as a key-value pair in an object.

Your changePage should look like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#machine_manuals", {transition: "slide"});
```

The documentation for the method, and the options available can be found here:
http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does not work. :(

I think that something with the ajax-call does not work, because If I try an alert instead of the changePage, it also does not work.

Comment: Ok!
I found some hint to my Problem.

The SAP-Server call is from the form-submit and not from my ajax-call.
He never goes in the method above.

On my Server, I made that:

l_view = create_view( view_name = 'main.htm').
call_view( l_view ).

But I does not wanna call the main.htm . 
I wanna call the second page in the jquery mobile project. (main.htm#machine_manuals)

How does that work?